# JavaScript image gallery with next/previous and image preview

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

A client has a request for an image gallery which previews the next/previous image with arrows to navigate between the images.

Example: Visit http://www.louisvuitton.com/front/#/eng_US/Collections/Women/Handbags and click "Clutches" on the left hand side. Click on a bag which is not in the center, notice that the gallery scrolls to that position.

Does anyone know of a javascript library that already exists that does something similar?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://ibrandstudio.com/inspiration/30-best-jquery-image-gallery-plugins-portfolio-website.

And pay attantion to http://www.eogallery.com/. It seem that it's the closet one to your example.